# Why are grams usually only expressed as milligrams, grams or kilograms?

Tags: soft-question, conventions, si-units

I'm a physics (and electronics and astronomy, etc.) enthusiast. As I learn and research topics, I notice that many SI units are often expressed using a variety of prefixes, such as in electronics where we use microvolts, millivolts, volts, kilovolts, and sometimes megavolts. In computer storage, the prefixes kilo, mega, giga, and tera are very familiar.

In physics, however, for large quantities of mass, I usually just see kilograms used with scientific notation:

$$2\times10^6 kg$$

This could also be expressed as 2 *gigagrams*, but I've never heard anyone use that particular unit (which might be why it sounds silly). I understand that it is impractical to use a prefix for something as large as the mass of the sun, $2\times10^{30}$ kg, but wouldn't it be more appropriate to use grams, as in $2\times10^{33}$g?

Is this simply out of convention, or is there a more logical reason?

Comment: I wondered the same thing about "decibel" - as *deci* is also just a prefix, but you never hear people talk about *just* [Bel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Conversions)

Comment: Micrograms (µg) are also common.  The most common example is probably on a packet of multivitamins, but you'll certainly see them in lab work.

Comment: There might be a cultural aspect to this too. For example, in some continental European countries using the metric system, people will quite happily talk using centimetres and centilitres, whereas people using the metric system in the UK will generally jump straight to millimetres and millilitres (e.g. 330 ml bottle as opposed to 33 cl).

Comment: I've often thought the same about "meter". Usually you'll hear/see things measured in thousands or millions of kilometers, when the same could easily be expressed as megameters or gigameters. (Interestingly enough, I'm getting spelling errors for "megameter" and "gigameter" in my browser - it's like the words don't exist.)

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I am not sure that [decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) is a good example because that is measured on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Indeed, a kiloBel would be associated with a supernova-scale event.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a weird quirk of the SI system that the base unit of mass is the kilogram, not the gram. So you'll see a lot of things expressed in kilograms.

Of course, scientists in a given field tend to standardize on certain choices of units without any regard to the SI recommendations. And this makes sense; the units you use should be the ones that make your values most understandable for the intended audience. SI is only intended as a fallback to enable unambiguous communication between groups that don't otherwise have a shared convention (especially between experimentalists and theorists). So sometimes you'll see quantities expressed in grams or tons or solar masses or whatever because that is the standard in the context you're looking at.

Comment: Chemists (and some others) still like working in the CGS system (centimeters, grams, seconds) as their base units. One could argue that kilogram is the base unit because most of thing world around us is easier to deal with in kilograms rather than grams. Humans tend to have a hard time dealing with large (or small) numbers outside of the hundredths-hundreds range.

Comment: Plus nobody wants to stand on a scale in the bathroom and have it say "75000."

Comment: A dozen years ago my undergrad astrophysics classes all used cgs units as well.

Comment: Other interesting units regarding mass are often used, evensome that easily could be based on grammes. Remember explosives? `kilotons`, `megatons`.. I was really suprised when I heard those two for the first time, yet `kiloton` gives much better impression than `gigagram`.

Comment: @tpg2114 On the other hand, if it said "0.75"...

Comment: @Izkata I don't know about you, but if the scale says I weigh .081 megagrams, I don't want to be reminded that I weigh *any* fraction of a "megagram"

Comment: I'd love if mine said "It's over 9000"

Answer (score 9):

The identification of units with a standard measure happens at the anthropic level: distances, times etc units are developed from the everyday usage, thus convention is the main answer. When a discipline becomes mathematical and is concentrating at a special power of the unit, the use of  scientific "nick names" saves times and mental effort for people manipulating and discussing and communicating observations and data.

For weights,  once one gets to  atomic dimensions,  weight, in the sense of gravitational interactions, becomes irrelevant and is replaced by mass in energy related units .

So your question is about astronomic units, and it possibly is just convention that astronomers and cosmologists use kilograms, although note that often in popularizations one gets "sun masses" as a unit. In the large weights  case it is more or less convention. After all on antropic grounds we also have tons for large weights.

Comment: Micrograms are extremely commonly used in various fields, and are definitely not atomic...

Comment: @Joe  changed it , as 1 Hydrogen Atom Mass = 1.007825 amu = 1.673534 x10^-24 gram.

Answer (score 8):

Gigagrams and megagrams are completely valid names.  But if you are often using the base unit of kilograms, it's not obvious how many of those you have.

It is (by the rules of the BIPM) incorrect to use any additional prefix with kilograms since it already has a prefix.  $10^3kg$ may be rendered as a *megagram*, but (I think) with a loss of easily noting the relationship to a single kilogram.  It may not be rendered as a *kilo-kilogram*.

Comment: Of course a _megagram_ is a _tonne_.

Comment: And *gigagram* has also a really familiar name of *kilotonne*. Boom.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: However, when a kiloton goes boom, it is a (non-SI) unit of _energy_, conventionally equal to one teracalorie.

Comment: Heh, good point!:)

Answer (score 4):

Divisive prefixes are fairly commomplace for the gram: I've certainly seen *nanogram* (ng) and *microgram* ($\mu$g). Multiplicative prefixes are indeed rare, and it seems that the most common is to affix to *tonne* (think bomb comparisons), e.g. *megatonne* (Mt). The tonne is [accepted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonne) for use with SI units.

Comment: While the metric ton is, indeed, a good unit the use in explosive energy is a little divorced from simple masses by the conversion to energy. A better example might be civil engineering.